# Angular: using dynamic InjectionTokens based on routes?

Tags: angular, service, dependency-injection, routes

I am wondering how to initialize a service that has a dependency on another service and a complex object used to instantiate a dependency within the service. Currently, I am using an InjectionToken to push the complex object into the service, but I *need to dynamically push different complex objects to the service, depending on the route the user takes*.

To demonstrate the problem, imagine I have InterestingService that depends on HelperService and an object containing parameters that is used for instantiating an internal service class:

## InterestingService

```
...
@Injectable()
export class InterestingService {

  interestingObject: InterestingObject;

  constructor(private helperService: HelperService,
              @Inject(PARMS) private parms: ParmsTemplate) {
    // parms e.g. {value1: 'aaa', value2: [1,2,3]}
    this.interestingObject = new InterestingObject(parms);
  }

  doSomething() {
    this.interestingObject.doSomethingAwesome()
  }
}
```

The parameters must follow a specific format:

## ParmsTemplate

```
export interface ParmsTemplate {
  value1?: string,
  value2: number[]
}
```

The service is consumed by a component:

## SomeComponent

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { InterestingService } from './interesting.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-some-component',
  templateUrl: './some.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./some.component.css']
})
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public service: InterestingService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.doSomething();
  }
}
```

The InjectorToken definition, along with a bunch of pre-defined recipes, is contained in PARMS:

## PARMS and canned RECIPES

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';
import { ParmsTemplate } from './parms';

export const PARMS = new InjectionToken<ParmsTemplate> ('parms.for.interesting.objects');

export const RECIPE_1: ParmsTemplate = {
  value1: 'aaa',
  value2: [1,2,3]
}

export const RECIPE_2: ParmsTemplate = {
  value1: 'bbb',
  value2: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
}

export const RECIPE_3: ParmsTemplate = {
  value2: [1,2]
}
```

The InjectionToken is initialized in AppModule:

## AppModule

```
...
import { RECIPE_1, RECIPE_2, RECIPE_3, PARMS } from './parms';
import { InterestingService } from './interesting.service';
import { HelperService } from './helper.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    SomeComponent
  ],

  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  exports: [ ],
  providers: [
    InterestingService, 
    HelperService,
    {
      provide: PARMS, useValue: RECIPE_1
    }
  ],
  entryComponents: [ ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And finally, the routes are defined:

## AppRoutingModule

```
...
import { NgModule }             from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { SomeComponent }     from './some.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'recipe1', component: SomeComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/'}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

This is all fine and good and it works...for one recipe. What I would like to do is extend my routes to include the other recipes:

```
...
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'recipe1', component: SomeComponent },
  { path: 'recipe2', component: SomeComponent },
  { path: 'recipe3', component: SomeComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/'}
];
...
```

The problem is that my InjectionToken can only be set to one value in AppModule.

1. Is there a way that I can specify which InjectionToken to use, based on route?
2. Is there a different way I can use to still keep the InjectionToken strategy but get different recipe parameters pushed into my shared service?
3. Do you think this is a better job for a *factory provider*?  And if so, how would you suggest I go about using a factory provider to use my different recipes and serve them up for related routes (e.g. /recipe2 brings you to SomeComponent with InterestingService initializing InterestingObject with parms from RECIPE_2)?
4. What about using route data? If so, how can you inject route data into a service? (Actually, this is quite easy and possibly the best solution: inject Route into InterestingService, pass the recipes as route data for their specific routes, and fetch the recipe data in the service using route.data(). )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I refactored my code to eliminate the need for route based data and instead created a service to hold the canned recipes and to initialize InterestingObject. I'm much happier with this solution.

Prior to that, I was able to use route data but I had to play around with ActiveRoute and the different route events to get at that data in the component. While this worked, it impacted my ability to create dynamic recipes and to reuse the component, since it was awkward to try to push data into the route. The service was clearly the correct answer.

I set up my canned recipes as methods on the shared service. Unfortunately, I had to set them up as instance methods so that my expressions in HTML could reference them. I tried making them static variables, but the expressions couldn't seem to see statics on the service, but they can see instance references no problem.